# How to create user in MediaWiki using database

Tags: database, mediawiki, user-management

I've tried to add a new user with phpmyadmin of my host but it didn't work. After I 
add a new record in user table (same of other users info) and tried to login with 
my new username to the MediaWiki, the system said `user doesn't exist`.

Answer (score 7):

Don't touch the database manually, if you need to do this server-side, there's a script for that called `createAndPromote.php` in `maintenance/`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to import many user at a time ,you can use [ImportUsers extension](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:ImportUsers), it allows you to import a CSV file (with user list) into the system.

You can not insert records in User table for it has a password field which being encrypted by a PHP function.But for other tables like tw_group or user_groups,you can change it directly in database.

Answer (score 0):

Was evaluating BlueSpice (based on MediaWiki) and came to that point, too.

Problem in my case was: In table `user`, column `user_name`, entries must have capital first letter! E.g.

```
|user_name|
|test     |
```

is not working.

```
|user_name|
|Test     |
```

is working.

---

Also, regarding the "password" problem mentioned in the other answer: You can create it by yourself. Here's a quick and dirty solution using some webtools.

*Create random hex for salt (32 bit)*
https://www.browserling.com/tools/random-hex

*Turn salt to base64*
https://base64.guru/converter/encode/hex

*Create key from password (30000 Iterations; dkLen 512; PBKDF2WithHmacSHA512)*
https://8gwifi.org/pbkdf.jsp

*Create Key String (replace >>XX<< with the values from above)*

```
:pbkdf2:sha512:30000:64:>>SALT_IN_BASE64<<:>>KEY_STRING<<
```

Ps: For the user_token I used a random 32bit hex.

---

*Be extremely careful when making direct changes to the database. Always test extensively. This is not for newbies who copy from StackOverflow without understanding what they are doing!*